# is do without parameters superfluous?

Tags: coffeescript

I am new to Coffeescript, and I am learning by studying someone else's Coffeescript code. There I see statements such as

```
do @mymethod
```

I think that `do` here is not needed because it does not capture any new variables, because it has no parameters. Am I right?

Comment: `do @m` is `this.m()`, maybe someone is afraid of parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly to mark this question as answered:

```
class C
    mymethod = -> console.log "mymethod"

    with_do = -> do @mymethod
    with_this = -> this.mymethod()
    with_at = -> @mymethod()
```

The three `with_...` methods will compile to the exact same JavaScript code.